# Xcode refactor doesn't rename setter and getter when I rename property name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, refactoring, getter-setter

Renaming property works only property name, but doesn't rename its getter and setter method.

For example, in the following code, when I rename propertyA to propertyB, `self.propertyA = @"ccc"` and `return propertyA` is renamed. But `-(void)setPropertyA:` and `-(NSString *)propertyA` is not renamed.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *propertyA;

-(void)setPropertyA:(NSString *)propertyA
{
    self.propertyA = @"ccc";
}

-(NSString *)propertyA
{
    return propertyA;
}
```

It's very dangerous if I forget to manually rename getter and setter.

How to make Xcode rename getter and setter when I rename property?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried renaming a property in Xcode 4.5.2 and it **did** rename the getter and setter.  Also, I think it's bad style to write `self.propertyA` in your setter

Comment: (Got interrupted and ran out of time to edit the previous comment.)  I think it's bad style to write `self.propertyA` in your setter.  Better to name the instance variable `_propertyA` and write `_propertyA = @"ccc"` so there's no confusion about when you're going through the setter and when you're modifying the variable directly.

Comment: @DavidHull 
Thanks for your comments. I tried renaming in Xcode 4.5.2 after I read your comments.
But renaming works only if I selected the property in the file(.h or .m) which the property defined in.
When I selected the property in the other files, the getter was renamed but the setter was not renamed.
And both setter and getter are not renamed if property is private (defined in class extension).
So when renaming property, we should select the property in .h file and remember to manually rename setter and getter of private property.

Comment: @DavidHull and thanks for pointing out about `self.propertyA`. I was wrong. it is not bad style but it is bug. `setPropertyA` is called recursively and infinitely by `self.propertyA = @"ccc";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. However, in the case above you don't need to. In the simple case you should just use `@synthesize propertyA`.

The Xcode refactoring tools are unfortunately still in an early stage of development.